# writing all 1s or 0s to 23k640 SRAM

Tags: memory, arduino

Hi please find my code below, I am trying to write to SRAM. please help
my code below reads the output from a cell but i can't write to that cell

```
 CS: pin 12  
 MOSI: pin 8
 MISO: pin 10
 SCK: pin 9
 
*/

#include <SPI.h>

//SRAM opcodes
#define RDSRAM        5  //00000101 
#define WRSRAM        1  //00000001
#define READ          3  //00000011
#define WRITE         2  //00000010
 int *ptr;
int CS = 12;
int CSS = 8;
char buf [90];
int response_pair;
int  entryval;
 int  codeAddr = 545;
char s [90];

//char value = *(char*)0x5C;

  uint8_t Spi23K640Rd8(uint32_t address){ 
  uint8_t read_byte;

digitalWrite(CS,LOW);
SPI.transfer(READ);
//SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 16) & 0xff);
SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 8) & 0xff);
SPI.transfer((uint8_t)address);
read_byte = SPI.transfer(0x00);
digitalWrite(CS,HIGH);
return read_byte;
  }

void Spi23K640Wr8(uint32_t address, uint8_t data_byte)
{
  SPI.transfer(WRITE);
  SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 16) & 0xff);
  SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 8) & 0xff);
  SPI.transfer((uint8_t)address);
  SPI.transfer(data_byte); 
}
void setup(void) {
// char *ptr;
// char myvar[1] = {545};
  
  uint64_t i; 
  uint8_t value;
  ptr=&codeAddr;
 /* all pins on the Port B set to output-low */
  pinMode(CSS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CSS, HIGH);
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2500);
  SPI.begin();


     for (i=0; i<=8192; i++) {  // Do all memory locations, 64 Kbit SRAM = 65536 / 8 = 8192
    
    Spi23K640Wr8(i, (uint8_t)i);
    value = Spi23K640Rd8(i);
    Serial.print((uint64_t)value, DEC);
     
    if ( !(i % 32) && !(i==0) ) { // Every 32, do a new line and don't do the first item either
      Serial.println(value);
    } else 
    {       // Other wise, print a comma
      Serial.print(",");
    }
    
    
  }
  
   while (!Serial) ;
   int response_pair = Spi23K640Rd8 (codeAddr);
    Serial.println ("Enter Challenge");
    //Spi23K640Wr8();
    delay(500);
}   

void loop() {
    //while (!Serial) ;
    
    
   int response_pair = Spi23K640Rd8 (codeAddr);
   if (Serial.available ())  {
        
        int n = Serial.readBytesUntil ('\n', buf, sizeof (buf)-1);  //.toInt();      //save read value method to n 
        buf [n] = '\0';
        sscanf (buf, "%o", &entryval);                                   //check values
       
       sprintf (s, " buf %s, response_pair %o entryval %o", buf, response_pair, entryval); //point the values from the pointer
       
        if(entryval == response_pair  )
        {
            Serial.println ("RESPONSE PAIR MATCHES ");
            Serial.println ("loading address......");
            Serial.print   ("CRP address output = ");
            Serial.println (Spi23K640Rd8(codeAddr), DEC);                          //prints out specific address
            Serial.println ("Authenticate Chip");
           
            Serial.println (s);
            
            //delay (500);
       }
       else if (response_pair != entryval) 
       {
            Serial.println ("INTRUDER ALERT!!!Wrong challenge");
            Serial.println (s);                                           //print the values in different types
            delay (n);
            
       }
       // return;
        
       // while (!Serial) ;
        
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println ("Enter Another Challenge");                          //start the process again
        
        
       //Serial.println (s);                                           //print the values in different types 
    }
  
        
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
//Serial.println("Hello LoRa");
//delay(50);
//ptr++;
}
```

i was able to read the power up state but haven't had any luck writing to the SRAM cells
any suggestions will be appreciated. i am on a tight schedule.
disregard beloww

We have established that In order to evaluate the properties of the SRAM as a PUF, we perform a number of specifically selected tests to investigate the behaviour of the start-up values of the SRAM memory
•   The technique can be viewed as an attempt to read multiple cells in a column at the same time, creating contention that is resolved according to process variation
•   An authentication challenge is issued to the array of SRAM cells by activating two or more wordlines concurrently
•   The response is simply the value that the SRAM produces from a read operation when the challenge condition is applied
•   The number of challenges that can be applied the array of SRAM cells grows exponentially with the number of SRAM rows and these challenges can be applied at any time without power cycling
•   providing an array of different responses on different chips ; these challenges are SRAM cells arranged in rows and columns where SRAM cells in each column and array share a worldlines
•   SRAM cells in each column in the array share common is a graph illustrating the number of unbiased  bit lines

Comment: I removed the C tag. this is C++. how can you now know what programming language you're using?

Comment: What is CSS ?  Why do you set it up as an output? does it interere with MOSI: (pin 8) (you have that in the comments above).  Also what flavor of Arduino are you using?  I could not easily find the cip corresponding to this SPI pinout.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, yes, the CSS interferes with the MOSI as I used it to print out the address.  i am using am hope RFM 95 Lora board connected externally to a 23k640 SRAM chip. please see data sheet for clarity

Answer (score 0):

The CS line is not asserted during the write operation, and the SRAM uses 16 and not 24-bit addresses.  You can try changing your read and write functions to something like this:

```
uint8_t Spi23K640Rd8(uint16_t address) {  // <-- change from uint32_t to uint16_t
    uint8_t read_byte;
    digitalWrite(CS, LOW);   // That's good

    SPI.transfer(READ);      // Read @ 16-bit address, that's good

    SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 8) & 0xff);
    SPI.transfer((uint8_t)address);

    read_byte = SPI.transfer(0x00);

    digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
    return read_byte;
}

void Spi23K640Wr8(uint16_t address, uint8_t data_byte) {   // <-- change from uint32_t to uint16_t

    digitalWrite(CS, LOW);   // Was missing.
   
    SPI.transfer(WRITE);     // write @16-bit address

    // SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 16) & 0xff);  // <- BUG!!! this byte is not expected!
    SPI.transfer((uint8_t)(address >> 8) & 0xff);
    SPI.transfer((uint8_t)address);
    SPI.transfer(data_byte);

    digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);   // clear CS.
}
```

Note: You should also consider renaming these functions to make your code easier to read.

How about replacing

```
uint8_t Spi23K640Rd8(uint16_t address);
void Spi23K640Wr8(uint16_t address, uint8_t data_byte);
```

With

```
uint8_t SRAM_23K640_ReadByte(uint16_t address);
void SRAM_23K640_WriteByte(uint16_t address, uint8_t data_byte);
```

Or whatever you see fit. Keep in mind that our eyes and brain have a much easier time reading shorter, pronounceable words.  When the brain is too busy reading long mumbo jumbo, thinking about other things, like what the code does, becomes more difficult.

Comment: currently playing with it. Thank you